# How to connect two Maven modules in one?

Tags: java, maven

I have parent `Maven` module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>atata</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>    
    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>runner</module>
    </modules>   
</project>
```

It has two children.

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>atata</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>runner</artifactId>
```

And

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>atata</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
```

In `Core` I have a code:

```
public class A {
    public void fun() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

In `Runner` module I use `A` class:

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().fun();
    }
}
```

But now my Runner doesn't see a class `A`. Is it possible to make it visible?

Comment: You need to create a dependency on "core" in "runner".

Comment: Just because they share a parent doesn't mean they're visible to each other. It's not the same concept as java packages. The children simply inherit some settings from the parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a dependency on `Core` in the `Runner` pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note that dependencies can only go one way, so you can't have dependency on `Runner` from `Core`, since it would cause a cyclic dependency which is not allowed. Seems like you have a good start judging from you module names though.

Answer (score 0):

add to the runner's `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
......
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
 ......
</dependencies>
```